# UIButton handle touch and then pass through?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, uikit

Is it possible to handle touch happened to UIButton and then pass it underneath to the next responder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

A valid approach is also to override the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method of `UIResponder`

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // handle touch
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded:withEvent:):

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However immediate UIKit subclasses of `UIResponder`, particularly `UIView`, forward the message up the responder chain. **To forward the message to the next responder, send the message to `super`** (the superclass implementation); do not send the message directly to the next responder.

---

#### Original answer

In order to determine which `UIView` in the view hierarchy should receive a touch, the method `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` is used. As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:):

> This method traverses the view hierarchy by calling the `pointInside:withEvent:` method of each subview to determine which subview should receive a touch event. If `pointInside:withEvent:` returns `YES`, then the subview’s hierarchy is similarly traversed until the frontmost view containing the specified point is found. If a view does not contain the point, its branch of the view hierarchy is ignored.

So an approach could be creating a `UIButton` subclass and override the method `-pointInside:withEvent:`

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point) {
        // The touch is within the button's bounds
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This will give you the opportunity of handling the touch within the button's bounds, but at the same time returning `NO` will make the hit test fail, passing the touch along in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thats nice, but doing side effects in method which should not produce them not that good. Maybe there are other possibilities?

Comment: I agree from a theoretical point of view is not the neatest thing ever, but the hit test mechanism is designed to retrieve a single view for handling the touch. You are somehow changing the design, so some quirk is expected. However if you can provide some extra details about your requirements it could help in finding alternative solutions.

Comment: @dig I edited my answer with an alternative approach

Comment: Yeah, was about to read that paragraph in Apple docs :) Thank you, this method is way better

Comment: Unfortunately first method doesn't work for this situation, I think they doesn't mean "propagate" as "pass beneath".

Comment: have you tried implementing both `touchesEnded` and `touchesBegan`?

Comment: Yes, I implemented all methods of touches* group